# Add border-spacing to ANTD Table Component ,and the checkbox is misaligned when checked?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I added border-spacing in index.css

```
body .ant-table table {
  border-spacing: 0 16px;
}
```

There is indeed a gap, but it causes the check box to be misaligned after checking

example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-snow-f7nui?file=/index.js

Comment: look like a bug, I can post an issue to GitHub to see if it can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the class of the cell that has the checkbox, its `ant-table-selection-column`.

The solution I used for this was style this class directly and remove border spacing from those `td's` like;

```
.ant-table-cell.ant-table-selection-column {
    border-spacing: initial;
}
```